# Why use Flask's Redis extension?

Tags: python, flask, redis

What is the advantage of using the Flask Redis extension in this example...

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.redis import Redis


app = Flask(__app__)
app.config['REDIS_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['REDIS_PORT'] = 6379
app.config['REDIS_DB'] = 0


r = Redis(app)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", **r.hgetall("temp.index"))
```

...over a regular Redis connection instance?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

import redis


r = redis.Redis()

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", **r.hgetall("temp.index"))
```

Comment: Have you considered asking whoever wrote it?

Comment: I just emailed the individual who started the project and asked him if he could answer my question here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Current maintainer of the package here, hi!

I think the two (admittedly minor) conveniences that the package provides are:

1. Integration with Flask's configuration management, so you can organize all your app configuration in the same place. You can add your Redis database URL next to the one for PostgreSQL or whatever you're using, and it'll be picked up automatically when you initialize the FlaskRedis app.
2. Automatically attaching to your Flask application, so you don't have to keep importing your Redis instance across modules, as it's already always with you, accessible like this: `app.extensions['redis']`. But if you want to import it anyway, you can also import the module with `import flask.ext.redis`.

Comment: __NOTE__: From the Flask 0.11 docs: "As of Flask 0.11, most Flask extensions have transitioned to the new naming schema. The flask.ext.foo compatibility alias is still in Flask 0.11 but is now deprecated – you should use flask_foo." I'm assuming `flask.ext.redis` is no exception?

Comment: @franklin yes, I switched to `flask_redis` and it is all good